# Memcached error in fuelPHPH, error code 47

Tags: php, memcached, fuelphp

I have problem with memcached in fuelphp.

i installed memcached and set everything as it should be and when i run my app i get following error.

**Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]: Memcached returned error code "47" on write. Check your configuration.**

I know that configuration file in fuelphp is correct because it works on other computers, so that is not the issue. Something is wrong with my memcached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

47 means MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED, and you get it when your memcached connection goes into a tcp timeout or passes it's retry limit. It's generated by libmemcached, and is outside your control.

So you need to figure out why your memcached server became (temporarily) inaccessable.

Comment: ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/memcached/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist

Comment: @NikolaTasic Could you please mark the answer as "solved"? It would make "valuable" answer easier to notice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered the same problem and carried out a decision that problem is with our php-memcached module but not with FuelPHP at all. This error is not permanent for us and appears only at one server out of four.

Is this error permanent for your configuration?

Comment: ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/memcached/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist

that solved the problem